# Prevent access to login page

Tags: php, session, authentication

How can I prevent access to the login page for logged in users. I want to redirect them to the homepage if they access the login page (when already logged in), which is www.example.com/login.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your are maintaining  [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for the users than simple on login page add this code on top of the page :

```
<?php 
session_start();  
if(isset($_SESSION['user_data']))
{
//redirect to desire page:
header("location:home.php");

}

?>
```

In above code i am considering that you have creating a session variable after successful login.

Comment: This works perfectly fine, clean and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple. Just check to see if they are logged in at the top of the page just like you would on any pages that only logged in users can see. But instead of redirecting them to the login page if they are not logged in, redirect them to their home page if they are. The logic is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to do this (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if they already have an active session.

Place this right at the top of your login.php file

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

Then use this to check the session changing myusername to what ever your value is for the usernames make sure you place it in between the body tags

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:../index.php");
}
?>
```

Just change the index.php url to suit your needs.

Comment: This is also a valid answer, thanks. I will keep this in mind even it's the same theory from Harshal.